# Are links from Guestbook especially Main-iGB useful for SERP ranking?

Tags: links, backlinks

I had noticed that many webmasters on health sites are creating so many links in guestbook, specially Main - iGB sort of guestbooks. These looks like do folllow link,
should I also filled over hundred links from this sort of guestbook. What do you think?

Comment: Twos words... `HELL NO`

Comment: Focus on content and gaining natural links, not only will your visitors love it, so will Google.  If you make links via blogs comments, guest books, slides, non relevant directories, forum signatures, forum profiles, web profiles and so forth, at some point you will feel the [WRATH OF THE PENGUIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Penguin).

Comment: Thanks simon. This is about ethical working. And, I seriously love this. But, I do want to learn about their ways. I have noticed that one webmaster in my niche has 158 links from such guestbook.

Comment: check this site...

Comment: http://www.russiansingapore.com/guestbook/?mode=1&page=61

Comment: I had written to its admin... they are having a guestbook which is full of useless guestbook comments and links... totally irrelevant too. But, why they added such guestbook. Please give some views over this... I'll be waiting for your answer.

Comment: Why did they add a guestbook?? Who knows? Some software include it. Spammers love this because of the ignorance of the webmaster. They use automated spam software to create millions of links like so many dog turds in other peoples yards. There is no advantage to having a guestbook that is spammed. It seriously effects your trust rank. And there is no advantage in the major search engines having links in guestbooks. It does still effect smaller regional search engines hence why it is still done. Plus, I suspect there is a chromozone missing that makes these people holes of a particular type.

Answer (score 1):

This is classified as blackhat SEO and will be penalized by most major search engines including Google. If you try to do this you will find that your SERP rankings will go down as a penalty.